# Jasmine spyOn: self.foo() reverts to original implementation inside Promise.then()

Tags: javascript, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I have a function, which acts as an event handler to a form submission. Inside this function, I make an asynchronous `fetch` call, which has a `then` chain.

In my test file, I do `requestSubmit()` to call the event handler of the form, and then test that `onFormSuccess` method has been called.

This is an approximation of my test file:

```
describe('my source file.js', function() {

    'use strict';

    var form;

    beforeEach(function () {
        form = /* Instantiate as MyClass */
    });

    afterEach(function () {
       /* Remove event handlers from from*/
    });

   describe('myEventHandler',  function() {

        beforeEach(function() {
            jasmine.clock().install();
        });

        afterEach(function() {
            jasmine.clock().uninstall();
        });

        fit('should handle success', function() {

Line X:            console.log('before: form.onFormSuccess:' + form.onFormSuccess);
            // Output: my original implementation
            spyOn(form, 'onFormSuccess').and.callThrough();
Line Y:            console.log('after:  form.onFormSuccess:' + form.onFormSuccess);
            // Output: function (a) { return fn.apply(this, arguments); }


            // Mock the POST request that the eventhandler will make
             spyOn(window, 'fetch').and.callFake(function(){
             /* return a promise that resolves to a Response, with appropriate data so onFormSuccess will be called in event handler*/
});




            form.init(); // Initialises MyClass
 
            document.querySelector('myclass-input').value = 'foobar';
            // I need to insert some random data, since requestSubmit validates the form before calling the event handler
            document.querySelector('myclass-form').requestSubmit();
            // This calls the method myEventHandler
jasmine().clock().tick(6000); // Wait for the promises to resolve


             expect(form.onFormSuccess).toHaveBeenCalled();

         });
   });
```

This is my source file:

```
MyClass.prototye.myEventHandler = function(e){
    // This function manages the form submission

    e.preventDefault(); //disable actual form submision, as we will manually do a POST request using fetch.
    var self = this;
    /*
    get form data, make it url-encoded string
    */
    
    // Here, both self.onFormSuccess and this.onFormSuccess give the same output,
    // which is,
    // function (a) { return fn.apply(this, arguments); }
    // This is as expected from a spied upon function
Line A:    console.log('this.onFormSuccess:' + this.onFormSuccess);
Line B:    console.log('self.onFormSuccess:' + self.onFormSuccess);


    window.fetch(action, {
            method: 'POST',
            body: formData,
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'
            },
    }).then(function(data) { 
            return data.json();
    }).then(function(data) {
                if (data.success) {
Line D:             console.log('self.onFormSuccess:' + self.onFormSuccess);
                    self.onFormSuccess(data.success);
                } else if (data.errors) {
                    console.log('call onFormError');
                    self.onFormError(data.errors);
                } 
        }).catch(function(error) {
          /* error handling */
        }).then(function(){
          /* this then acts as a finally */
        });

}
```

In my test file,

`Line X:` prints the original implementation. This is Expected

`Line Y:` prints the spyOn implementation, as this is called after doing the `spyOn` call. Again, as expected.

Now, when the source file is called, ie `myEventHandler` function, then,

Line A, Line B: both print the spyOn Implementation. This is as expected since this method has been spied upon.

But, at `Line D:`, which is inside the `then()` function of my mocked `fetch` call,

the output prints the original implementation of my `onFormSuccess` function, instead of the spied upon function.

This causes my test spec to fail

```
Expected spy onFormSuccess to have been called.
    <Jasmine>
```

Why is the self.onFormSuccess method going back to it's original implementation? Why does it not stay spied upon? How do I force it to stay spied upon?

---

The dependencies of this project include:

```
    "jasmine-core": "3.4.0",
    "karma": "4.3.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "3.1.0",
    "karma-firefox-launcher": "1.2.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "2.0.1",
    "sinon": "7.4.1",
    "svgo": "^1.2.2",
    "tinypng-cli": "^0.0.7"
```